# Entity Linq query to get the parent of a parent

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Whats the correct (and important most efficient) LINQ query to get the parent of a parent in an entity.

For instance:

A person has many feet, which have many toes all connected by key relationships.

Given the toeID i could find the foot easily enough because the toe would have a footID field and the foot would have a personID field. How can I combine these two queries into a single one?

(I prefer Linq as lambda functions but query language is ok too)

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: If you're using EF then each `Toe` has a `Foot` property and each `Foot` has a `Person` property.  You simply query for the `Toes` collection and `Include` the `Foot.Person`.

Comment: David, my current method is to simple query for the parent and then query for the parents parent. Two simple Where querys.

Comment: jmcilhinney, The EF proxy properties are not awaitable and so not asynchronous. I'd like to keep my db queries Async if i can.

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = people.Single(x => x.PersonId == feet.Single(y => y.FootId == toe.FootId).PersonId);
```

Comment: I considered doing that but nesting queries sounds like a bad idea to me. Won't this essentially map to two sql queries anyway?

Comment: I seems it produces a single query, albeit one using a subquery rather than a join, but I'm sure the database will make efficient use of that. It's a one round trip anyway.